# How does vector class takes multiple argument and create a array out of it?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, class-template, stdinitializerlist

[vector example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRsXB.png)

```
vector<int> a{ 1,3,2 }; // initialize vectors directly  from elements
for (auto example : a)
{
    cout << example << " ";   // print 1 5 46 89
}
MinHeap<int> p{ 1,5,6,8 };    // i want to do the same with my custom class
```

Any idea how to do accept multiple arguments in curly braces and form an array?

`std::vector` class uses `std::allocator` to allocate memory, but I do not know how to use this in a custom class.
[VS Code shows `std::allocator`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU9is.png)

[I have done the same but it does not work like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPRBJ.png)

```
template<typename T>
class MinHeap
{
    // ...
public:
    MinHeap(size_t size, const allocator<T>& a)
    {
        cout << a.max_size << endl;
    }
    // ...
};
```

noob here ....

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector Take a look at the last constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any idea how to do accept multiple arguments in curly braces [...]

It is called *[list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)*.
You need to write a constructor which accepts the [`std::initilizer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (as *@Retired Ninja* mentioned in the comments) as argument, so-that it can be achieved in your `MinHeap` class.

That means you need something like as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list

template<typename T> class MinHeap final
{
    std::vector<T> mStorage;

public:
    MinHeap(const std::initializer_list<T> iniList)  // ---> provide this constructor 
        : mStorage{ iniList }
    {}
    // ... other constructors and code!
    
    // optional: to use inside range based for loop 
    auto begin() -> decltype(mStorage.begin()) { return std::begin(mStorage);  }
    auto end()  -> decltype(mStorage.end()) { return std::end(mStorage);  }
};

int main()
{
    MinHeap<int> p{ 1, 5, 6, 8 }; // now you can

    for (const int ele : p)   std::cout << ele << " ";
}
```

**([Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vMhGrefn5))**